# external routing is not working in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

here is my main.js file

```
import express from 'express';


// route file are import here
import router from "./user-route/admin-route.js";

// **************** global variable are define here

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(("./user-route/admin-route.js"));
///  ***************** routing are created are here

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello from the server");
});

// ******************  server is created here

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is Ready and Running on Port 5000");
});
```

and here is my external routing file

```
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();


const admin = (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("Hlo from the dashboard");
}

/// admin routers are defined here 


router.route("/admin").get(admin);

export default router;
```

how I can connect the external routing with main.js file. here I am using the module method.

if i try with require method than it's work properly. i am not sure but i think problem is here

```
app.use(("./user-route/admin-route.js"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the issue:

```
app.use(("./user-route/admin-route.js"));
```

You can't pass a filename to `app.use()` and expect it to work (in fact, it throws an error).

But you were close:

```
app.use(router);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is something similar to this? What you're missing really is the app.use routing part, there are two parameters for that.

```
app.use('/admin', AdminRouter);
```

Main.js file

```
import express from 'express';


// route file are import here
const AdminRouter = require('./user-route/admin-route.js')

// **************** global variable are define here

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(express.json());
///  ***************** routing are created are here

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello from the server");
});

app.use('/admin', AdminRouter);


// ******************  server is created here

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is Ready and Running on Port 5000");
});
```

external routing file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/// admin routers are defined here

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```